# Получить значения с input

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица по нажатию добавляться поля в первом поле через `autocomplete` выводятся модели, во втором поставщики так же, при нажатие на выбранного поставщика нужно отправить модель и поставщика на сервер, не получается добавить модель выбранного поставщика ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var provider = ["<?php echo  $provider; ?>"];
        var model = ["<?php echo  $model; ?>"];
        var i=1;
        $("#add_row").click(function(){
            $('.addr'+i).html("<td><input name='model[]'  class='vendor_code'  type='text'></td>" +
                "<td><input name='provider[]' class='provider' type='text'></td>" +
                "<td><input name='quantity[]' type='text'></td>" +
                "<td><input  type='text' readonly class='price"+(i+1)+"'></td>" +
                "<td><a id='delete_row' class='minus button'><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td></td>");

            $('.addr'+i).find('.vendor_code').autocomplete({ source:model,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                }
            });

            $('.addr'+i).find('.provider').autocomplete({ source:provider,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var provider  = ui.item.value;

                    var model = $("input[name='model[]']").val();

                    console.log(model);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'index.php?route=invoice/invoice/barcode_error&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
                        data:{
                            "model":model,
                            "provider":provider
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("input.price"+i).val(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr class="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++;
        });
        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
            if(i > 1 ){
                $(".addr"+(i-1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
        });
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
        jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();
    });
</script>
```

`var model = $("input[name='model[]']").val();` не получается получить модель соответствующего поставщика, побывал через `class  var model = $('.vendor_code').val();` но так только первая модель потягивается виденная в первом поле.

Comment: От куда взялось `row` в этой строке `var model = row.find("input[name='model[]']").val();`

Comment: забыл убрать ` var model = $("input[name='model[]']").val();`